# How to manipulate last row in justifyContent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a ScrollView with the following styles:

```
flexDirection: 'row',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
```

Which centers my grid of elements like this:

[image]

However, if there is one element in the last row, it is in the middle of the row:
[image]

I would like it to be aligned to the left, while being justified:

[image]

My question is: is it possible to do this only with styles? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

with [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid) :

```css
.root {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.case {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
  <div class="case"></div>
</div>
```